# I'm learning to use mongoose to connect with MongoDB atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a connection with MongoDB atlas and require all the documents in the collection but every time I get an empty array []. I'm watching youtube and reading the docs from mongoose website but I can't figure it
this is my code:

```
    var express = require("express");
    var cors = require("cors");
    const multer = require("multer");
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    
    var app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    
    
    const connection_String = "URL_example";
    
    
    const Subjects = new mongoose.Schema({
        location: String,
        space: Number,
        topic: String
      });
    
    const MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', Subjects);
    
    
    
    mongoose.connect(connection_String, {dbName: 'Schoolclasses'})
      .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB Atlas...'))
      .catch((err) => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB Atlas...', err));
    
    
    
    
    
    app.get('/lessons', async (req, res) => {
        const data = await MyModel.find()
        res.send(data);
        console.log(data);
      });
    
    
    app.listen(4000, () => {
         console.log("server is running on port: 4000" + " MongoDB connection is successful" );
        
    })
```

Comment: What is your collection name?

Comment: jQueeny
 the name is "Subjects"

Comment: The default collection name for that model would be "subjects".  MongoDB is case sensitive.  Can you verify with the data explorer that there is data in the 'subjects' collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a Model, mongoose takes the first parameter of the `mongoose.model()` method and looks for a lowercase, pluralised collection name based on that value. So, in your case you have:

```js
const MyModel = mongoose.model('MyModel', Subjects);
```

Mongoose will look for a collection named `mymodels` because `MyModel` --> `mymodels`.

What you want to do is this:

```js
const subjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   location: String,
   space: Number,
   topic: String
});
    
const Subject = mongoose.model('Subject', subjectSchema);
```

Then when you make requests to the database use the model name associated with the collection.

```js
app.get('/lessons', async (req, res) => {
   const data = await Subject.find() //< Use Subject here
   console.log(data); //< Log data before response
   res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: it worked thanks a lot. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @user18165556 you're welcome.